# Why `this.synchronized` instead of just `synchronized` in Scala?

Tags: multithreading, scala, this, synchronized

In an example of working with JDBC in Scala, there is a following code:

```
this.synchronized {
  if (!driverLoaded) loadDriver()
}
```

Why `this.synchronized` instead of just `synchronized`?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

In scala `synchronized` is not a keyword, as in java.

It is in fact a member of [`AnyRef`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/AnyRef.html), which is scala equivalent for java's `Object`.

So to answer your question, you can either use `synchronized` or `this.synchronized`, just as you can do `toString` or `this.toString`.