# scala notify() vs notifyAll()

Tags: multithreading, scala

Given the following implementation of the producer-consumer problem in scala

```
class PC {
  var buffer = null.asInstanceOf[Int]
  var set = false

  def produce(value: Int) = synchronized {
    while (set) wait()
    buffer = value
    set = true
    notify() }

  def consume: Int = synchronized {
    while (!set) wait()
    val result = buffer
    set = false
    notify()
    return result; }
}
```

There are 3 things I don't quite manage to see:

1. Why, if I'm using notify instead of notifyAll, I end up in deadlock; Where should I use notifyAll, for in produce or consume?
2. Shouldn't I have an object e.g. lock, and call lock.synchronized, lock.wait and lock.notify? Why does it work like this, don't produce and consume have 2 different monitors associated? Why does 'notify' from produce notifies 'wait' from consume?
3. How does a monitor work exactly in scala (in our case)? Does it use a signal-and-continue policy? how do processes from a waiting queue on a certain condition get moved to a runnable queue? Is there a queue for each condition/lock (e.g. lock1.wait, lock2.wait, etc).

Comment: P.S. I have one producer and multiple consumers.

Comment: try to use http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html for producer/comsumer, it will be more simple

Comment: I suggest you to avoid using wait() and notify(), that are very low-level fine-grained primitives, and use the stuff in java.util.concurrent

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is really a question mostly about Java concurrency. Scala concurrency is built on top of the Java concurrency model, but the syntax differs. [In Scala, `synchronized` is a method of `AnyRef`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7826822/why-this-synchronized-instead-of-just-synchronized-in-scala), and the above syntax is equivalent to using the keyword `synchronized` to write *synchronized methods* as in the following Java code:

```
public class PC {
  public int buffer;
  public boolean set;
  public synchronized void produce(int value) { 
    while(set) wait();
    buffer = value;
    set = true;
    notify(); 
  }
  public synchronized int def consume { 
    while(!set) wait();
    int result = buffer;
    notify();
    return result; 
  }
}
```

For more detailed coverage of the Java concurrency model, peruse the [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html). You may want to investigate the [Java Concurrency Library](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html). For instance, you could implement the same thing using a [Blocking Queue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) with a capacity of 1.

In answer to your questions:

**1. Why, if I'm using notify instead of notifyAll, I end up in deadlock; Where should I use notifyAll, for in produce or consume?**

You probably have a race condition (rather than a deadlock) because the `notify()` in the `consumer()` is received by some other consumer thread, rather than the producer thread, but that's just a guess. As far as whether to use `notify()` or `notifyAll()` and in which methods, some recommend that `notifyAll()` always be used. And, in this case, you can use `notifyAll()`, because you are waiting in a conditional while loop -- which you should always do for various reasons described in the documentation of [wait()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28long%29). However, you could also choose to use `notify()` as an optimization in the `producer()`, because I'm assuming you only want one consumer to consume the buffer contents. With the current implementation, you must still use `notifyAll()` in `consume()` or potentially expose yourself to a situation where one of the consumers is notified rather than the single waiting producer resulting in the producer waiting forever.

**2. Shouldn't I have an object e.g. lock, and call lock.synchronized, lock.wait and lock.notify? Why does it work like this, don't produce and consume have 2 different monitors associated? Why does 'notify' from produce notifies 'wait' from consume?**

You do have a lock. It's an implicit lock on the `PC` instance and in Java there's one and only one monitor per object although there may be many entry points. The `wait()` in `consume()` is notified by the `notify()` in `produce()`, because they are both waiting for a lock on the same resource -- the `PC` instance.  If you want to implement more flexible or finer-grained locking, then you can use various strategies from the the [Java Concurrency Library](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) such as [Locks](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/package-frame.html).

**3. How does a monitor work exactly in scala (in our case)? Does it use a signal-and-continue policy? how do processes from a waiting queue on a certain condition get moved to a runnable queue? Is there a queue for each condition/lock (e.g. lock1.wait, lock2.wait, etc).**

For a good description of how the JVM performs thread synchronization, read this: [How the Java virtual machine performs thread synchronization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6584355/how-does-the-synchronize-functionnality-work-in-java). For bit more detail from a chapter from the same author, you can read [Inside the Java Virtual Machine](http://www.artima.com/insidejvm/ed2/threadsynch.html).

Answer (score 1):

#### Why, if I'm using notify instead of notifyAll, I end up in deadlock?

As you may have observed, the problem you are witnessing does not occur if there is only one producer and one consumer (because in that case, `notify` does the job you expect it to do, which is to let the next producer/consumer make its move).

If you have more than one producer or consumer however, the following problem occurs: Lets say there are 2 producers and a single consumer. In this scenario, the following is bound to happen if you use `notify()`:

1. One of the producers runs, and calls `notify()`
2. Instead of the consumer, the other producer is notified
3. The producer awoken by `notify()` now waits infinitely, because the consumer will never get notified

If `notifyAll` is called instead, there will always be a consumer which gets notified, thus the problem that a producer or consumer waits indefinitely for the other party neverr arises.

#### Shouldn't I have an object e.g. lock, and call lock.synchronized, lock.wait and lock.notify?

Your lock object is the `PC` object. A Scala `object` is simply a singleton instance of a class which the compiler generates for you. Since your `object` is actually a class instance of the class `Object`, it also inherits its `notify`, `notifyAll` and `wait` methods.